# Remove x and y from geom_sf_text

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

Borrowing from https://r-charts.com/spatial/maps-ggplot2/, I want to plot an object using ggplot2 and label them using geom_sf_text. I can plot and adjust settings just fine, but can't determine a way to remove the 'x' and 'y' axis labels.

So, the data is:

```
map <- read_sf("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/R-CoderDotCom/data/main/shapefile_spain/spain.geojson")
```

And the map is:

```
ggplot(map) +
  geom_sf(color = "white", aes(fill = unemp_rate)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none", panel.grid=element_blank(), axis.text = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = name))
```

With the resulting map:
[image]

Removing the geom_sf_text row results in no axis labels, but every time I add that line the labels return. I've tried all the theme and aes commands I can think of, but nothing has worked.

Comment: Hm. Interesting. Try with `+ labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)` or `axis.title = element_blank()`.

Comment: Have you tried changing `theme()` and `geom_sf_text()` order and applying theme changes as a last step?

Comment: Indeed. Though  `x` and `y ` anre axis titles, so `theme(axis.title = element_blank())` should do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @stefan mentioned possibilities:

#### using `theme_void`

```
ggplot(map) +
  geom_sf(color = "white", aes(fill = unemp_rate)) +
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = name)) +
  theme_void()+
  theme(legend.position = "none", 
        panel.grid=element_blank(), 
        axis.text = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]

#### using `axis.title.x = element_blank()` ``axis.title.y = element_blank()`

```
ggplot(map) +
  geom_sf(color = "white", aes(fill = unemp_rate)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none", 
        panel.grid=element_blank(), 
        axis.text = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),  
        axis.title.y = element_blank())+
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = name))
```

[image]

#### using `labs(y = "", x = "")`

```
ggplot(map) +
  geom_sf(color = "white", aes(fill = unemp_rate)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none", 
        panel.grid=element_blank(), 
        axis.text = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks = element_blank())+
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = name)) +
  labs(y = "", x = "")
```

[image]

Comment: `theme_void()` and `labs(y = "", x = "")` both work great. I have a base sf that I am then adding labels to with a second call to geom_sf, so the `axis.title.x` command is tied to the first so hasn't worked for me in removing the x and y. Though I'm sure there is a solution to that as well. My preferred was  `labs(y = "", x = "")`.